# Google Plus SDK for Android : "Activity started without an EXTRA_ACCOUNT"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-plus, google-play-services

I am playing with the Google Plus sample app. When I click on "+1", I have the choice between "Ok" or "Share". When I click on OK, everything is fine. But when I click on "share", I have got an alert saying that "Google Plus app stopped" and the log hereafter. Any idea how I can avoid this problem ? Thanks !!!

```
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.plus/com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.ShareActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity started without an EXTRA_ACCOUNT
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity started without an EXTRA_ACCOUNT
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at brz.onCreate(PG:169)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.PostActivity.onCreate(PG:77)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.ShareActivity.onCreate(PG:156)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
11-04 11:07:58.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Google+ app that is fixed in the latest build that came out today: https://plus.google.com/101870761930221849874/posts/KohXe9pBGF6 Sorry about that.